# Check if a pandas.Timestamp is in a pandas.Period

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, period

```
# pseudo code: 
myPeriod.contains(myTimestamp)
```

I found the lack of such function in pandas quite surprising. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) if you have multiple values:

```
print df.index
PeriodIndex(['2015-11'], dtype='int64', name=u'', freq='M')

d = "2015-09-01"
d1 = "2015-10-01"
print df.index.isin([pd.to_datetime(d).to_period('M'), pd.to_datetime(d1).to_period('M')])
[False]

d = "2015-11-01"
d1 = "2015-11-01"   
print df.index.isin([pd.to_datetime(d).to_period('M'), pd.to_datetime(d1).to_period('M')])
[ True]
```

If you want compare only one `datetime`, easier is use (thanks [maxymoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854769/check-if-a-pandas-timestamp-is-in-a-pandas-period/35854920?noredirect=1#comment59376466_35854920)):

```
d = "2015-09-01"    
print df.index == pd.to_datetime(d).to_period('M')  
[False]

d = "2015-11-01"    
print df.index == pd.to_datetime(d).to_period('M')  
[True]
```

Or with `Series`:

```
print df.a
0   2015-11
Name: a, dtype: object

d = "2015-09-01"
d1 = "2015-10-01"   
print df.a.isin([pd.to_datetime(d).to_period('M'), pd.to_datetime(d1).to_period('M')]).values
[False]

d = "2015-11-01"
d1 = "2015-11-01"
print df.a.isin([pd.to_datetime(d).to_period('M'), pd.to_datetime(d1).to_period('M')]).values
[ True]
```

Comment: Thank you for such prompt reply, I knew I was missing something. But since we are here, I have one further question: How do I make myself aware of the existence of "isin"? It is not in Pandas webpage "Time Series / Date functionality"

Comment: You can find it in [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin)

Comment: this isn't really about `isin`, the essence of your answer is converting the timestamp to a period and checking for equality, what's realling going on is the expression `myTimestamp.to_period(myPeriod.freqstr) == myPeriod`

Comment: if out of the context manipulation of indexes, I will just use your earlier : myPeriod.start_time < myTimestamp < myPeriod.end_time, I figure it would be faster and more readable. Obviously I was hoping for a 'Timestamp in Period'

Answer (score 11):

You can access the boundaries of a period with `start_time` and `end_time`, hence the expression for whether a time is within a period would would be

```
myPeriod.start_time < myTimestamp < myPeriod.end_time
```

Comment: Thank you, but I expected something more concise, considering this is python, and we are using pandas on top of python.

Comment: in my opinion this is fairly concise and pythonic, most languages won't let you combine a double inequality like this

Comment: Oh nice, I did not know that (the double inequality thing) was possible in python, I thought that was a pseudo code. Thanks.